# Cannot get an image in a keyframe to center horizontally

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am having a huge headache with an image I have. It will not center horizontally no matter what I do. I have tried setting it to absolute and relative. Setting left to 50%, adding in `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, setting the image to display as block with the margin on the left and right as auto.

What else can I do to get this thing centered? Whenever I added `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, it centered, but the keyframe rotate got all out of wack and instead of the hand waving in the same position, the hand moved down the page.

The snippet does not fully demonstrate what it is doing.

```css
.red {
  background-color: #0085A1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hand {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  /*transform: translate(0, -50%);*/
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
}

img.hand {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(75deg);
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <img class="hand" alt="HELLO">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both `translate()` and `rotate()` at the same time.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2whaLx52/)**

```css
.red {
  background-color: #0085A1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.hand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
}
@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(75deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ywCRl0A.png" class="hand" alt="HELLO">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This works great. Do I have any flexibility to move down the hand from the top at all? Side question: Why won't this work on my phone? The image is static and does nothing.

Comment: Yes, and you probably need prefix the rules, I didn't use any for the simplicity, this tool is handy- https://autoprefixer.github.io/